# Is there any way to change getConfig method (AbstractHelper class) to be a static method?

Tags: magento2, system-config, system-configuration

I'm new to Magento 2 and from what I know, in order to retrieve config values, you need to extend the AbstractHelper class and create a method:

```
public function getConfig($config_path)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $config_path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

Is there any way to transform this method into a static method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need such functionality?

Comment: The reason for this need is that other static functions made in the class would need to call this method to retrieve configuration values.